# Where to put user configurations/defaults for spacemacs?

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, config

I am a vim user trying to covert to emacs/spacemacs, but I'm having a horribly difficult time configuring things that seem like a breeze others.

I want to limit the fill to 80 (mainly for .txt files and .org mode.. I thought the default was 80 anyway? Is this only for certain file extensions?), and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566727/how-to-set-the-default-width-of-fill-mode-to-80-with-emacs) question which gives this line:

```
(setq-default fill-column 80)
```

but **where do I put this?**. I have tried putting it in 
`init.el`, the `dotspacemacs/user-config` section of my `.spacemacs`, and the `dotspacemacs/user-init` section of my `.spacemacs`. The keyboard combos `C-u 80 C-x f` work for setting the fill to 80 while I'm in the buffer, and `M-q` adjusts the fill if lines are overfilled.

Am I missing something here? From what I can see, [this](http://thume.ca/howto/2015/03/07/configuring-spacemacs-a-tutorial/) (dated) blog of a spacemacs contributor suggests placing such lines in `dotspacemacs/user-config` and **not** in `init.el`. Meanwhile, Eivind Fonn, another spacemacs contributor who has publicized his dotfiles on github, has everything in an `init.el` and no `.spacemacs`.

I should add that other statements such as `(gobal-hl-line-mode)` and `(setq-default evil-escape-key-sequence "jk")` work as expected for me. Do I have a big misunderstanding of how to configure spacemacs as my own or am I just mistaken on the intricacies of this specific function?

**EDIT**

I was mistaken on the command that I needed. I actually want `auto-fill-mode` instead of the default fill value. I tried putting

```
(auto-fill-mode 1)
```

in `dotspacemacs/user-config` and in `dotspacemacs/user-init` but neither work. If I simply execute it as a command, it works fine.

I decided to scrap spacemacs and start learning emacs with evil-mode from the ground up. If I put the `(auto-fill-mode 1)` into my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, it works fine. I even made a function that auto-enables this only in org-mode. Learning emacs from scratch has given me a much better understanding of how emacs works, but now that I am manually installing packages and configuring things on my own, I want all the pre-configured-ness of spacemacs back! So now my question is **where do I put `(auto-fill-mode 1)` in my `.spacemacs`?**

**Version info:**

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Emacs: 24.4.2
Spacemacs: Develop Branch (Release 0.105.x)

Comment: How did you determine that putting `(setq-default fill-column 80)` in `dotspacemacs/user-config` doesn't work?

Comment: @bmag I updated my question - I had a misunderstanding of which command I needed.

Comment: I updated the answer with a section about activating `auto-fill-column`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## setting default value for auto-fill-column

Normally, you'd put such configuration in `dotspacemacs/user-config`, which is a function in your dotfile (`~/.spacemacs`).

It's possible to use a `~/.spacemacs.d/init.el` as your dotfile instead of `~/.spacemacs`, which I assume is what Eivind Fond does.

The original default value for `fill-column` is 70. In current develop branch, Spacemacs configures `fill-column` to a default of 80, so you probably don't need to do it yourself.

As Kevin wrote in the comment, keep in mind that we only set the default value for `fill-column`, and the value can be different in buffers or modes that set their own value for `fill-column`.
When the value is changed for a certain major-mode, it is usually done in the mode-hook. So if, for example, you want Org buffers to have a fill column of 72, you'd add something like this to `dotpsacemacs/user-config`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (setq fill-column 72)))
```

I've used a `lambda`, but I recommend using named functions instead of lambdas when you want to add them to hooks, since it makes it easier to use `remove-hook` later if necessary.

You might want to read the sections about [buffer-local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer_002dLocal-Variables.html) and [hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html) in the manual.

## enabling auto-fill-mode

`auto-fill-mode` is a local mode, so when you add `(auto-fill-mode 1)` to your user-config, it activates auto-fill-mode only for the buffer that is current when that line is evaluated. Instead, you want to add `auto-fill-mode` to the hook of any major-mode where you want to activate auto-fill-mode. For example, if you want to activate auto-fill-mode in Org buffers, you need to add it the `org-mode-hook`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
```

If you want to activate auto-fill-mode everywhere, you'd probably want to hook it into `text-mode-hook` and `prog-mode-hook`. This way auto-fill-mode will be enabled in every major mode that derives from `text-mode` or from `prog-mode`, so basically that covers (almost?) every buffer where it's logical to have auto-fill-mode turned on:

```lisp
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
```

These lines should be placed in `dotspacemacs/user-config` as well.

Comment: And don't forget that `setq-default` only sets the default value, which is only visible if buffers and modes don't have their own value for the variable. From the doc: `The default value of a variable is seen in buffers
that do not have their own values for the variable.`  So you might have the statement in the right place, but still not be able to see the effect of it in org mode or whatever.

Comment: @Kevin That's good to know. Is there a way to get around this with hooks or something? (I updated my question with the statement that I actually want).

Comment: Kevin, thanks I've added a paragraph about local values overriding the default value

Comment: @bmag is right in pointing out that hooks are the way to go to set up customizations on buffers with particular modes. Nice comprehensive answer on the topic. I can't think of anything else to add. Good luck with your new life of configuring and customizing emacs (hopefully not endlessly)!

Comment: Great. That did the trick. Thanks a ton. Just to be sure I'm understanding correctly, when you say that auto-fill-mode is a "local mode", is that synonymous with "minor mode"?

Comment: Yeah, I used "local mode" for minor mode here to differentiate from minor modes that are global. For example, `global-linum-mode` is a global minor mode, so calling `(global-linum-mode)` activates line numbers in every buffer where it makes sense. You can't do that for `auto-fill-mode` because there is no `global-auto-fill-mode`.